# How to send notification from one user to other in android studio using firebase

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

Please give the stepwise procedure to send the action notification from one user to other and after getting the notification , user have to give some response on the basis of that it may go to different activities.
Please suggest procedure/tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

There are hundreds of tutorials online for various ways to do this, and they all depend on your framework, language, and available API
A good start would be Youtube
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDpxBTjvPys